# Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring unknown module "12"

Tags: react-native

The problem comes soon after `react-native init tech_stack1`, `react-native run-iso` command and the last Xcode update (9.1).

It alternate with "No bundle URL present".

This my package.json

```
"name": "tech_stack1",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.50.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
}
```

Comment: Did you try ```npm install```? Also, could you put your index.js file's contents here.

Answer (score 1):

After some upgrades to @latest versions of react-native, redux and react-redux I was able to get rid of this error, also by performing a `react-native start` command in a new terminal window ( to get rid of no bundle URL present).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had change several files with replace and gave error, example,
a Component TextInput was Text Input, the code not identify the component and show this message. When I fixed the wrong components, worked again.